# PigLatin won't output correctly

Tags: java, string, for-loop

Java doesn't output the code correctly when the word starts with a consonant. It outputs:

> Exception in thread "main"

It works when the word starts with a vowel .

```
import java.util.*;

public class PigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = getWord();
        String pigLatinWord = convertToPigLatin(word);
        System.out.println(pigLatinWord + " is the word translated in PigLatin");
    }

    public static String getWord() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word = keyboard.nextLine();
        return word;
    }

    public static boolean isVowel(char character) {
        if(character == 'a' || character == 'e' || character == 'i'
                            || character == 'o' || character == 'u') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String convertToPigLatin(String word) {
        String pigLatinWord = "";

        if(isVowel(word.charAt(0)) == true) {
            String latin = word + "yay";
            System.out.print(latin);
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
                if(isVowel(word.charAt(x)) == true) {
                    String partOfWord = word.substring(0,word.charAt(x));
                    String secondPartOfWord = word.substring(word.charAt(x));
                    String combination=secondPartOfWord + partOfWord;
                    pigLatinWord = combination + "ay";
                }
            }
        }
        return pigLatinWord;
    }
}
```

1. I want to keep all my methods the same
2. I don't want to alter the code too much

Comment: you have an extra 'u' in the constraints of your if statement in the isVowel(). Start by removing this. Also, can you please post the Stacktrace of the error? Give us an example of how it's not outputting correctly. What did you input? What did you expect?

Comment: If the word begins with a vowel, add the ending “yay” to the end of
the word. For example, indian in piglatin is indianyay.
- To translate words that begin with a consonant (or multiple consonants) into
piglatin, you must remove all of the beginning consonants until you get to a
vowel. Then move the removed consonants to the end of the word along with the
ending “ay”. So, china in piglatin is inachay, school in piglatin is oolschay, and
cat in piglatin is atcay.

Comment: please edit your original post so that everyone in the SO community reading your question has all of the information needed without having to scour through comments :)

Comment: Friendly reminder to accept an answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are accessing substrings with .charAt, which is causing the error. Just use the index x.

Second error, once you've found your string, you want to finish. Add a break at the end of your if statement.

Finally, your code is wrong in that you need to deal with the case of all consonants; if you have a word like rhythm, your pig latin word will be rhythmay. With previous two fixes, this does not occur. So check that if all the letters are consonants make a second case.

So your last else section should look like this with all the changes:

```
    } else {
        Boolean wordIsAllConsonants = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
            if(isVowel(word.charAt(x)) == true) {
                String partOfWord = word.substring(0,x);
                String secondPartOfWord = word.substring(x);
                String combination=secondPartOfWord + partOfWord;
                pigLatinWord = combination + "ay";
                wordIsAllConsonants = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(wordIsAllConsonants)
            pigLatinWord = word + "ay";
    }
    return pigLatinWord;
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay new approach to helping someone. Rather than just tell you the answer let's learn!

I ran your program with input "piglet". Surprise! I got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 105
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at com.tutelatechnologies.tapfortap.server.support.PigLatin.convertToPigLatin(PigLatin.java:40)
at com.tutelatechnologies.tapfortap.server.support.PigLatin.main(PigLatin.java:9)
```

I know what you're thinking. WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?!?!? Well, if you look in your stack trace (if you plan to be a dev, get used to doing this) you will see StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when you are calling substring() method. It even  tells you the line on which the error occurs in your code!

```
PigLatin.java:40
```

Fabulous! So walk through your code with an example. Heck, try it on paper with the word 'piglet' like I did. Specifically pay attention to the values for x that you are passing into the substring(). Also, let me remind you of the definition of the [substring methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). Make sure you are good on the input parameters to this method on whether that index is included or excluded in the resulting substring.

Feel free to comment on this for more hints!

Comment: I edited the bad indentation in OP's code and now the line numbers have changed. I thought I should mension it if ppl are copy pasting and compiling :)